# How to set the QTreeWidget's header color and hide the dividing line?

Tags: c++, css, qt, qwidget

I want to change the background color of the header when I use the QWidget. I tried the following methods but they didn't work:

```
QTreeWidgetItem * header = ui->treeWidget->headerItem(); 
header->setBackground(0, QBrush(QColor(185,192,201)));
header->setBackgroundColor(0, QColor(185,192,201));

setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section { background-color:red }");
```

I also want to know how to hide the header's dividing line?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a method to change the header's style,but I don't know why my previous method did not work.

```
QHeaderView::section {                          
    color: black;                               
    padding: 2px;                               
    height:20px;                                
    border: 0px solid #567dbc;                  
    border-left:0px;                            
    border-right:0px;                           
    background: #f9f9f9;                        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use only the stylesheet?

```
YourQTreeWidget QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: red; // for the bakcground
    border-right: none; // right-border of each section
    border-left: none;  // left border of each section
}
```

Comment: I've tried it,and your code doesn't work,but I've found the following code useful.I don't know why your code doesn't work.
`QHeaderView::section {       
        color: black;        
 padding: 2px;        
 height:20px;        
 border: 0px solid #567dbc;     
 border-left:0px;       
 border-right:0px;       
 background: #f9f9f9;      
}`

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/25191-Why-can-t-I-set-backgroung-of-a-QTreeWidget-s-header-item) (and as you see in your example) `setBackgroundColor` does not work for header item (I suspect that this is due to difference between header and row items).
You should to reimplement `QHeaderView` or to try option described above.